# how to execute test cases on a specified node url using selenium grid 4

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid, remotewebdriver, selenium4

In selenium grid 4, The session distribution takes care of by the selenium hub itself. (I.e if we mention the hub URL, it will automatically assign the available nodes)
So How we can mention the remote URL to launch the browser in a user-specific URL

```
driver.set(new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(HubURL), cap));
```

Comment: Why do you ever need to use specific URL?

Comment: @AlexeyR.      There are two jobs to be executed from the same machine with different users. So in that case I have to control the execution nodes from my end.
If that is the case I have to specify the node url for particular job execution

Comment: Try to approach with cabability extension set up when you start your node through `stereotype` config (see [--driver-configuration](https://webelement.click/en/selenium_grid_4_complete_guide_to_configuration_flags#_driver_configuration) option of a node). Then use that extra capability for the run you would like to forward to a specific node. Grid should parse that capability and route it to matching slot.